# User entered value validation and level of error catching

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

May I ask should the error catching code be placed at the lowest level or at the top as I am not sure what is the best practice? I prefer placing at the bottom, example a, as

Example a

> ```
>    public static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         string operation = args[0];
>         int value = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
>         if (operation == "date")
>         {
>             DoDate(value);
>         }
>         else if (operation == "month")
>         {
>             DoMonth(value);
>         }
>     }
>     public static void DoMonth(int month)
>     {
>         if (month < 1 || month > 12)
>         {
>             throw new Exception("");
>         }
>     }
>     public static void DoDate(int date)
>     {
>         if (date < 1 || date > 31)
>         {
>             throw new Exception("");
>         }
>     }
> ```

or example b

> ```
>    public static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         string operation = args[0];
>         int value = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
>         if (operation == "date" && (date < 1 || date > 12))
>         {
>             throw new Exception("");
>         }
>         else if (operation == "month" && (month < 1 || month > 31))
>         {
>             throw new Exception("");
>         }
>         if (operation == "date")
>         {
>             DoDate(value);
>         }
>         else if (operation == "month")
>         {
>             DoMonth(value);
>         }
>     }
>     public static void DoMonth(int month)
>     {
>     }
>     public static void DoDate(int date)
>     {
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept that will help you understand the consequences for each of your example

separation of concerns

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The technical validation of input should be done in front of the consuming methode. Technical validation means things like: Are there enough parameter? Perhaps: Do they have the right "type"?

The information validation should be done right before the input is interpreted. So you are conform with the OO principles.